# Should a toddler drink milk if has congestion?

Tags: pediatrics, milk, mucus-phlegm, nasal-congestion, sinus-congestion

Are there any studies that prove drinking milk while having a cols is a bad practice - especially for toddlers?

Answer (score 2):

The following is for adults:

Relationship between milk intake and mucus production in adult volunteers challenged with rhinovirus-2.
 [(PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16373954):

> In individuals inoculated with the common cold virus, milk intake was
>   not associated with increased nasal secretions, symptoms of cough,
>   nose symptoms or congestion.